# How to search from date?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php.
My database date is 2013-10-28.I want to search only date (28).
____-__-28 This is wanted format.
Please help.

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
    <?php
    if ($List[$i]['mmpautono'] != "" && $List[$i]['mautono'] != "" && $List[$i]['Eudate'] == '%%-%%-08') {
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
    ?>
</td>
```

Eudate date is search date.

Comment: date is come on database.It is ok.I want to search that date only by date " && $List[$i]['Eudate'] == '%-08')" like this,but this is not work.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to search for dates where the day of the month is 28, is that it? If so, try

```
... WHERE DAYOFMONTH(dateColumn) = 28
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth

Take note, this could be a slow query as you can't index the results of the date functions. If speed is essential, you could create another column called `day_of_month` or something, index it and populate it with `DAYOFMONTH` using `INSERT` / `UPDATE` triggers.

Then you'd just need to search

```
... WHERE day_of_month = 28
```

Comment: If there are a lot of rows, it'll almost definitely be pretty slow.  If this'll be a common query, you might want to add a column just containing the day-of-month as a tinyint or something, and index/search that.

Comment: @cHao I was just writing that up :)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter data from database like this and then perform operation in front end.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName where  EXTRACT(DAY FROM columnName) = 28;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL [LIKE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_not-like)

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE dateField LIKE '%-28'
```

OR

OR [DAYOFMONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth)

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE DAYOFMONTH(dateField) = '28'
```

Comment: Hi Phil, apologies, I just go the same answer on internet. If you want, I can delete my answer.

Comment: It's quite alright to have two similar answers, as long as there's no plagiarism going on.  Don't worry about stepping on people's toes :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE datecolumn LIKE '%-28'
```